# Cannot show a dialogfragment within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment, its layout has a button, and I add a click listener to it, on which the onclick executes this:

```
    CFrag_FE_Datepicker dp = new CFrag_FE_Datepicker();
    dp.show(getFragmentManager(), "dp");
```

Where CFrag_FE_Datepicker is a dialogframent

However, the fragment didn't pop up. I set a breakpoint inside the onclick proc, it breaks as expected, and it happily goes past dp.show() but simply nothing happens.

I move the button to an Activity but this time it works without problems.

Why is that so?

Here is the source of the fragment, sorry if there are many irrelevant codings here:

```
package com.Prime.no2_andr;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CFrag_FE_Datepicker extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener{
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    boolean IsShowCal = true;
    CFrag_dp fragDP = new CFrag_dp();
    CFrag_cal fragCal = new CFrag_cal();
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runPager;
    boolean IsLoaded = false;
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//      sectPagerAdp = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
//      mViewPager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);
//      mViewPager.setAdapter(sectPagerAdp);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_fe_datepicker, container, false);
        v.findViewById(R.id.btn_More).setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (IsLoaded) return;
//        IsLoaded = true;
//        runPager = new Runnable() {
//
//            @Override
//            public void run()
////            {
//              getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.rl_Cont, fragDP).commit();
//            }
//        };
//        handler.post(runPager);
    }

    /**
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onPause()
     */
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
//        handler.removeCallbacks(runPager);
    }

    public void onClickMore(View btn) {

    }
    public FragmentTransaction ExecAddFrag(FragmentTransaction ft){

        ft.add(R.id.rl_Cont, //fragDP
                fragCal
                );
        return ft;
    }

    public static class CFrag_dp extends CFrag_dp_cal {
        public CFrag_dp() {
            super(false);
        }
    }
    public static class CFrag_cal extends CFrag_dp_cal {
        public CFrag_cal() {
            super(true);
        }
    }
    public static abstract class CFrag_dp_cal extends Fragment {
        boolean IsCal;
        public CFrag_dp_cal(boolean in_IsCal) {
            IsCal = in_IsCal;
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(
                    IsCal? R.layout.frag_fe_datepicker_cal : R.layout.frag_fe_datepicker_dp,

                    container, false);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        IsShowCal = !IsShowCal;
        /*
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.rl_Cont, IsShowCal? fragCal : fragDP)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            */
//      ((TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(IsShowCal? "T":"F");

    }


}
```

Comment: From where you are trying to show the DialogFragment? Is it a FragmentActivity?

Comment: Think so, but don't have the code with me right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using nested Fragments and you call getFragmentManager() on a child Fragment, the FragmentManager that will be returned is the parent's getChildFragmentManager() not the hosting activity's FragmentManager. Try calling `getActivity().getFragmentManager()` if that's the case.

Comment: Thx for answering, I'm always so confused, what's the difference between the parent's and child's fragment mgr? Are their any difference of effect on using each of them?

Comment: They are responsible for managing fragments in the different levels in the view hierarchy. If you want to use non-nested fragments (attach fragments in an activity), the host activity's fragment manager (call _getActivity().getFragmentManager()_ from the fragments) should be used for attaching/detaching any fragments to/from the host activity. Whereas for the child fragments in a nested fragments setup, you can use the Child Fragment Manager of the host Fragment by calling getChildFragmentManager() Reference: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Comment: @im_chc The difference is that instead of attaching all nested fragments to the Activity's fragment manager, each Fragment has its own child FragmentManager that can hold its child Fragments. This allows the child fragments to inherit state from the parent among other things. E.g. if you call setRetainInstance(true) on the parent, the children will also be retained. Typically if you use something like a ViewPager it is normal to have Fragments that represent pages nested in the Fragment that contains the ViewPager. You'd want to pass the child FragmentManager to the FragmentPagerAdapter.